# I cannot post JQuery generated input texts

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have this function: it works very well, it adds new rows to the table "stud_tbl".

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function carga_MatServSap(id){
var myTable = '' ;
var id_val = id.value;

var url = "get_sap_oper.php?id="+id_val;
$.getJSON(url, function(json) {
    $.each(json, function(k, v) {   
    myTable +=   "<tr class=\"style10\"><td>"+v["Matnr"]+"</td><td>"+v["Srvpos"]+"</td>    <td>"+v["Ktext1"]+"</td><td><input type=text id='user_name' name='user_name'></td></tr>";    
    });

$("#stud_tbl").html(myTable);

});
}
</script>
```

but, here comes the problem: once generated, the text fields (...) cannot be posted trough the form ("myForm")? can any one help me please?

The table before execute the function:

```
<table id ="stud_tbl"  align="center"></table>
```

Now the form begins:

```
<form id="myForm" name="myForm">
```

Here is the table with the rows added:

```
<table id ="stud_tbl"  align="center">
```

Here are the generated fields that i need to submit too.

```
<tr class=\"style10\"><td>aaaa</td><td>bbbb</td><td>cccc</td><td><input type=text id='user_name' name='user_name'></td></tr>
<tr class=\"style10\"><td>cccc</td><td>dddd</td><td>cccc</td><td><input type=text id='user_name' name='user_name'></td></tr>
....
```

//end of generated text fields or inputs.

```
</table>
```

the generated text fields just aren't posted! what can I do?
I'll really appreciate any help. thanks.

Comment: `<form>` is not a valid child of `<table>`. I suggest you wrap your table with the form element instead.

Comment: thanks, it was a mistake on the question box.

Answer (score 0):

I think the js line 9 should be:

```
myTable +=   "<tr class=\"style10\"><td>"+v["Matnr"]+"</td><td>"+v["Srvpos"]+"</td>    <td>"+v["Ktext1"]+"</td><td><input type=text id=\"" + k + "\" name=\"" + v["user_name"] + "\"></td></tr>";
```

Change "user_name" according to your data structure.

Comment: no, when i've writen corrected, mean that you was correct in respect of the field name "user_name", but the problem persist.